# MySQL asked during installation to Win7 whether I wanted TCP-IP connection

Tags: mysql

I last installed MySQL 7 years ago, and don't remember this being asked.  If it was, I don't remember my response.

Anyway, I said no today, because why open a port if you don't have to, right?

But I've got a resin-web.xml that wants this filled in:

```
<url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/''dbname''</url>
      <user>''username''</user>
      <password>''password''</password>
```

My first question is:  if I open Port 3306 (I guess by creating an Allowed program entry in Windows 7 Firewall), is that risky?

Is there a way to not have to do that and still get to the MySQL on the shared machine?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to connect to your database. So you need to open the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you'll have to open it, especially to connect remotely.  Just try to lock it down such that it's only accessible from the local subnet, and make sure your Windows machine is behind a firewall or router of some sort to prevent the evil kiddies from the internet.

Be sure to lock down your mysql users too.  Don't just allow root@% to access without a password, for instance.

You can also configure SSL connections in Mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-connections.html